# Grails 3 urlMappingsReport failed

Tags: mysql, rest, grails

I have created a Grails 3 Restful application, using MySQL as my database. The endpoints are working fine when I hit them with Rest Clients like Postman. 
I am using this [blog](https://giri-tech.blogspot.in/2016/05/create-secured-restful-api-app-with.html) for reference. But it fails when I try to run the command `grails url-mappings-report`.

Here is the output:

```
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:compileGroovy
:buildProperties UP-TO-DATE
:processResources
:classes
:findMainClass
:urlMappingsReport

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core


Configuring Spring Security REST 2.0.0.M2...
... finished configuring Spring Security REST

        ... with GORM support
2017-10-01 17:45:24.867 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   restTokenValidationFilter
      ↓
   restAuthenticationProvider
      ↓
   tokenStorageService
      ↓
   userDetailsService
┌─────┐
|  hibernateDatastore
↑     ↓
|  userPasswordEncoderListener
└─────┘


Context failed to load: Error creating bean with name 'restTokenValidationFilter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'restAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'restAuthenticationProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restAuthenticationProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenStorageService' while setting bean property 'tokenStorageService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenStorageService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userPasswordEncoderListener': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
:urlMappingsReport FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':urlMappingsReport'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 37.453 secs
| Error Command [url-mappings-report] error: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip'. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Grails Version: 3.2.10

Groovy Version: 2.4.10

JVM Version: 1.8.0_131

Answer (score 0):

Try using GORM version >= 6.1

I get the same issue with GORM version 6.0.12.RELEASE